# Magento 2 PHPCS coding standards

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, coding-standards, phpcs

I am creating a Magento 2.3 website from scratch. I am having **phpcs.xml** file on Magento root which contains the rules for PHPCS. These rules get triggered when the build is executed. I am confused about which rules should I use for this XML file ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Funnily enough this is something I came across today and wanted to experiment.

Took me a few mins to get my head around the setup. This should get you started:

Inside web root

```
composer require squizlabs/php_codesniffer:^3.4
composer require magento/magento-coding-standard
vendor/bin/phpcs -i
vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/
vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 app/code/Xigen/Extension
```

or dump to file

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 app/code/Xigen/Extension --report-file="Extension.txt"
```

Comment: I have added it to my setup and tried to run the phpcs, but it threw the error for app/bootstrap.php. Shouldn't it ignore this file ?

Comment: @ParthThakkar just scan your own stuff as I have done above

Answer (score 2):

Use the official Magento PHP CodeSniffer ruleset and standards, which you can find here: https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard

This repository includes its own ruleset XML file that should cover everything you need.

Installation and usage directions are on the linked github page. (Not copying them in since they're liable to change over time.)

Comment: I have added it to my setup and tried to run the phpcs, but it threw the error for app/bootstrap.php. Shouldn't it ignore this file ?