# Magento 2 PHPMD and Coupling Between Object classes (CBO)

Tags: magento2, php

I'm working on a Magento 2 CRUD functionality following the best practices (best described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2)). On the project I'm working on we are using PHPMD (php mess detector). Among other rules, we have the CBO limit set to 13 (which I understand is the default). My repository is implementing the `get`, `save`, `getList`, `delete`, `deleteById` methods and the limit is already 12.

What would be best practice if I need to add other methods to this repository without overlapping the PHPMD CBO limit? Should I break the repository in multiple ones? If so how would a directory and file naming and structure would look?

*P.S. I understand that helper classes are no longer encouraged in Magento 2.*

Comment: Magento by it's very nature is repetitive. Whilst I appreciate the merits of scanning code with phpmd you will struggle to get anything done. You are best sticking with m2 phpcs ruleset https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/277385/70343

Comment: yeah, I totally understand, but some times you don't get to chose the tools :( - should I also add SonarQube into the mix? you will then get restrictions such as number of dependencies you can inject in a constructor class which kinda kills the composition over inheritance principle. I'm trying to understand if there are ways to overcome this kind of situations and also follow best practices.

Comment: Oh no way! :( Yep magento relies heavily on this too. Sorry I can't help more